# Is there any japanese TTS voice to work with C# SpeechSynthesizer

Tags: c#, unicode, text-to-speech, speechsynthesizer

Is there any Japanese voice for C#'s SpeechSynthesizer TTS?
If so please state detailed information about it, better if documentation provided.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft's Agent had a set of free voices including Japanese based on the L&H TTS3000 engine.  The engines were SAPI 4 compatible.

Unfortunately the [Microsoft Agent site](http://www.microsoft.com/msagent/) seems to be unavailable at the moment

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft has a [list of third-party TTS engines here](http://www.microsoft.com/speech/evaluation/thirdparty/engines.mspx).  In particular, [NeoSpeech](http://www.neospeech.com/) has a Japanese TTS engine.

Also, apparently Japanese MS Office 2003 ships with a [Japanese TTS engine](http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?t=187837), but I don't have first-hand knowledge of this.

Comment: Is there any free workaround for this without having to install third-pary software on client PC?

Comment: No.  Microsoft does not have a Japanese TTS engine as part of XP, Vista, or Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [AquesTalk](http://www.a-quest.com/products/aquestalk.html)? You can find C# bindings [here](http://www.saturn.dti.ne.jp/~npaka/robot/aquestalk/index.html). I haven't tried them though.

The Windows version AquesTalk is free, they do have versions for other platforms. The same company has also [AquesTalk2](http://www.a-quest.com/products/aquestalk2.html) (Windows version is free for personal use, otherwise you need to buy a license).

Here's [a small demo (YouTube)](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ltK579omhVs).