# How to use Speech Synthesizer with Japanese?

Tags: c#, winforms, text-to-speech

I want to create a small Text-to-speech app in C#. I used Speech Synthesizer with English and it worked fine. But when I pass a Japanese sentence, it didn't work. I didn't receive any error messages. Do I need to install something else?

I tested this on Win 7 32-bit and Win 10 64-bit.

Comment: Do you have any voices installed for the Japanese locale you're using..? You can [check it here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms586870(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @Rob I installed Japanese voice (Haruka). When I call GetInstalledVoices, it always has one voice (Anna, Win 7) or two (Zira, David, Win 10).

Comment: Are you passing the correct locale to `GetInstalledVoices`?

Comment: I pass "ja-JP" and get nothing. I think the problem is Japanese voice setup file but can't find out why.

Comment: Versioning matters, if you want to use Haruka then you have to use the Windows.Media.SpeechSynthesis namespace.  That cannot work on Win7 or in a Winforms project.  A shopping guide for the legacy SAPI engine [is here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1402833/is-there-any-japanese-tts-voice-to-work-with-c-sharp-speechsynthesizer).

Answer (score 1):

Try to set CultureInfo of your application.

```
var ci = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("ja-JP");
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = ci;
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = ci;
```

You can set English or Japanese, checking the CurrentCultureInfo.

```
if (currentUICulture == "ja-JP")
{
    string colorsString = colors.Aggregate((first, Next) => (first += ";" + Next));
    string transColor = speak.Translate(colorsString, "en", "ja");
    string[] jaColors = transColor.Split(new char[]{';','、'});
    for (int i = 0; i < jaColors.Length; i++)
    {
        //
    }
    commands = new string[]{ "なし", "クリア", "イコール",
        "プラス", "マイナス", "掛ける", "分割", "追加" };
}

Choices commandsChoices = new Choices(commands);
GrammarBuilder gb = new GrammarBuilder(commandsChoices);
sr.LoadGrammar(new Grammar(gb));

Choices colorChoices = new Choices(colors);
gb = new GrammarBuilder(colorChoices);
sr.LoadGrammar(new Grammar(gb));

sr.SpeechRecognized += new EventHandler<SpeechRecognizedEventArgs>(sr_SpeechRecognized);
sr.SpeechDetected += new EventHandler<SpeechDetectedEventArgs>(sr_SpeechDetected);
sr.SpeechRecognitionRejected += new EventHandler<SpeechRecognitionRejectedEventArgs>(sr_SpeechRecognitionRejected);
```

I hopes this help you

antonio